# In joomla components, where should i store the database functions, and how to call them?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, architecture, joomla, model

I am now building my first joomla component.

I have 3 tables in it:
__questions
__resaults
__display

I also need the Joomla user table:

__users

I have a single view:
view.questions.html

this view gets data and also needs some database functions. It needs to:

1. Get   information from the user table.
2. Get   information from the resaults table
3. Get   information from the display table
4. -SET- information to the reaults table

Now, I know Joomla is built with MVC architecture. This, I assume, means no dealing with database in views.

Where should I store the database hendling functions, and how can I call them in the front end?

The function dealing with questions is in the question view model, no problem, but what about the other tables? Should I put the functions dealing with them in the question model as well, the helper file, or make models for each other table, and call them from the question view? If i should make other models, how do I call them from the question view?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: have you not read the Joomla documentation on how to create a basic component. It explains things like this ;)

Comment: view.questions.html does not look like a valid view to me. it should be more like view.html.php

Comment: I have read it all, it took me around 20 hours to understand it, as I am a novice. This part was a little messy in my mind -  and there fore I asked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model for each table.
You will then instantiate them from the controller to make them available to the views.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a lot of time and also learn a lot by using the Component Creator: http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/ It will do all the MVC stuff for you.